# Estimate the number of unique occurences per group

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame `df`:

```
CITY   ID_C
abc    123
abc    123
abc    456
def    123
def    456
def    789
def    789
```

I need to calculate the number of unique values of `ID_C` grouped by `CITY`:

```
CITY  TOTAL_UNIQUE_COUNT
abc   2
def   3
```

I tried this code, but get the error `ValueError: cannot insert ID_CITIZEN, already exists`:

```
df.groupby('CITY').ID_C.value_counts().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a direct method for that:

```
df.groupby('CITY')['ID_C'].nunique()
Out: 
CITY
abc    2
def    3
Name: ID_C, dtype: int64
```

For formatting:

```
df.groupby('CITY')['ID_C'].nunique().to_frame('TOTAL_UNIQUE_COUNT')
Out: 
      TOTAL_UNIQUE_COUNT
CITY                    
abc                    2
def                    3

df.groupby('CITY')['ID_C'].nunique().to_frame('TOTAL_UNIQUE_COUNT').reset_index()
Out: 
  CITY  TOTAL_UNIQUE_COUNT
0  abc                   2
1  def                   3
```

Comment: And if I just want to calculate the non-unique total? `df.groupby('CITY')['ID_C'].count()` ?

Comment: @Dinosaurius Yes. If you want to exclude `NaN`s (if there is any) you use `groupby.count`. Otherwise, you can use `groupby.size`.